# Exporting hi-res png with small dimensions at exact size

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, export, png, dimensions

I want to export an illustrator file...

- In PNG format
- Exact dimensions (55x20mm)
- High resolution

72 ppi does not save at high enough standard. 300 ppi makes the dimensions too large.

The end user should never use a file smaller than 55x20mm, so I want to give them the highest quality file possible at that size.

Thanks in advance!

[image: 72dpi]

[image: 300 dpi]

Comment: Hi dbaoc welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. What do you mean with 'exact dimensions'? Dimensions on-screen? Be aware that those a fully independent from the actual resolution, since pixel density differs from screen to screen. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: The site is great. I've ended up here a few times in the past.

By exact dimensions, I don't want the png to be seen at smaller than 55x20mm if possible, so i want to create a file at that size.

In general, when using illustrator and i want to create eg. a100x100mm file, i create and artboard of that size and when i export, it doest not export at that size, unless of course i export at 72 ppi - but the resolution is not good enough at that setting

Comment: please read into the (lack of) relationship between resolution and on-screen physical size. As I said, some screens have a way higher pixel density at a way smaller size. How should your *.png be displayed on an iWatch, for example?

Comment: @dbaoc - would it be possible to use SVG? That way you get a web-friendly vector artwork that can scale to any size without loss of resolution. The biggest issue I see with your request is that, unless you can control all the displays and pixels in the world, there is no way to ensure your image will be exactly 55x20mm. Another option is to drop your Illustrator artwork into Photoshop as a SmartObject and play with different resolutions until you find a good compromise between quality and size.

Comment: Thanks guys.

Maybe someday i can control all displays & pixels in the world (that'd be a cool comic book character)...

I get what you are saying re: on screen vs off screen.

I was hoping to give them a png version that would work for screen & print, but i get what you guys are saying.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To give the best possible quality file, and the exact size you have to send a vector based file. Svg or a pdf file (converted to curves or nodes) are two good options.

Asking a specific size in mm means that you need a printed file, so in that case the option to a rasterized file can be from 200 or 300 ppi for a rgb, cmyk or grayscale images to 1200 or 2400 ppi monocromathic files. In this cases the size you see on your screen does not matter.

If on the contrary, you need to see it on your screen you can not control the size on cm at all. Are you using a mobil phone or proyecting it in a movie theater? ... You simply can not.